# Slim framework app render

Tags: php, jquery, slim

I have two routes,get method where visualize all data, and post method where insert the data.In the get method using the app-render ('view name', and the data), and so good.In the method post I will do the same in order to see the end inserting the same page with a popup that contains a success message. The two methods have the same url, the problem is that when I render in the post method, I view the page with half of the contents because it does not recognize the data in hand with the get method.

```
$app->get('/url.html',function()use($app){
     //code
     $app->render('url.html', array('name'=>$variable1,'user'=>$variable2)));   

});
```

**I want to display the pop-up after insert**

```
$app->post('/url.html',function()use($app){

 //code

 $popup='$(function(){$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({modal: true, buttons: {Ok: function() {$( this ).dialog( "close" );}}});});';
 $app->render('url.html', array('popup'=>$popup)                                            

    )); 

});
```

**In the view "/url.html"**

```
<?php echo $popup ?>
```

But does not work

then summing up the view does not work in the post method and the popup

Comment: What doesn't work? What is it supposed to do? Do you get error messages? Is the problem PHP or javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the "popup-code" into on load:

```
$popup='$(function() { 
      $(window).load(function () { 
          $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({modal: true, buttons: {Ok: function() {$( this ).dialog( "close" )}}});
      };
});';
```

You can remove tabs and spaces from my example code when using, just put them in for legibility.

Edit: Are you wrapping your output into `<script type="text/javascript"><?php echo $popup; ?></script>`